# Django model request array

Tags: python, arrays, django, request, models

I am new to python and Django. I haven't found anything in documentations so I have to write here.

I have such problem.

I have cars table where you can find it's make, model. year and so on.
Usually i make request by just Cars.objects.filter(make=x, model=y, year=z)

I want to make search and all params are in array. There are many params and is it possible to make something like 
Cars.objects.filter(array)

Ok. How i am getting my data. It is regular post form which I send by ajax to my view class. I have list of allowed params which can be found in users request. I have different names for tableview name and input name, but i have everything i need in prepared array. It can take user's sent car-name Acura and make something like {'make':123}. At the end i have an array which is fully compatible with my db {'make': 123, 'model':321}. Can i make a request using this array and not write by hands every param?

Comment: have you made any search form and written its view yet? add it to your question, how you are getting params in array ?

Comment: you have an dict of search parameters, not an list, right? `{'make': 123, 'model': 'abc'}` is a python `dict`, not an array (which in python is called a `list` by the way). You know if you have a `dict`, let's say `params`, then passing `**params` in a function call will be the same as calling the function with each key of the dict set to its value: `Cars.objects.filter(**params)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if arguments are stored in this format:

```
args = [('make', 'x'),('model', 'y'),('year', 'z')]
```

You can try:

```
arg_dict = dict(args)
Cars.objects.filter(**arg_dict)
```